# MVC3 Form Validation causing an error in Qunit tests

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, qunit

I have been working with a MVC3 application that is using jquery form validation and in my script that interacts with the remote validation process to see if a record name is available I am using the

```
    $('#Name').rules().remote.complete = function (xhr) {
```

check to change form variables etc. When I reference that script from my QUnit tests I get the following error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined**

I can fix it by putting the following conditional above the .rules() check but is there a better way to do this?

```
if (document.forms.length > 0) {
```

I suppose I could fire up the page in IIS and do JS unit tests that way but that seems less isolated. I would not want to have this .rules() check in some other JS file because combining the JS files is a way to improve speed. Anyone ran across this and found a better way to do it? Thanks in advance.